# How to deal with cyclic mutable borrows

Tags: rust

I am working on building a small game in Rust and have run into a problem I'm not sure how to solve. Essentially I would like to have a Controller trait which has an update method. The update method should accept a mutable entity reference and have a mutable reference to itself. The problem is that I want the entity to own its controller, which results in me needing to do a double mutable borrow. Here is a Rust Playground link which demonstrates what I am trying to do https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f33f548bb72373f47757092fbb0b615d

```rust
trait Controller{
    fn update(&mut self, entity: &mut Entity);
}

struct MyController{

}

impl Controller for MyController{
    fn update(&mut self, _entity: &mut Entity){

    }
}

struct Entity{
    controller: Option<Box<dyn Controller>>    
}

impl Entity{

    fn update(&mut self){
        if let Some(controller) = self.controller.as_mut(){
            controller.update(self);
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let _entity = Entity{
        controller: Some(Box::new(MyController{}))
    };
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of an entity and controller? I'd like to see the broader context of what you're trying to solve.

Comment: Let's say we have entity A and entity B. Entity A and B need to follow the position of the mouse and entity A needs to change colours every second. I may want to just put the mouse position code in the entity update method and have a controller which changes the colour of entity A, or I could have the option to add multiple controllers to an entity and add a mouse controller to entity A and B. I don't have a concrete idea of what I'm trying to do yet, but this seemed like a flexible approach. It seems like I sort of want to use an entity component system like Specs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way that I've found to tackle this problem is by [splitting borrows](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/borrow-splitting.html). Instead of passing the whole `Entity` you would take everything that is required by the `Controller.update` method and put it in another struct (e.g. `EntityData`). Then instead of passing the entire `Entity` you would just pass the `EntityData`.

The `Entity.update` method would then look something like this:

```rust
impl Entity{
    fn update(&mut self){
        // Borrow the controller
        let controller = &mut self.controller;
        // Borrow the entity data
        let data = &mut self.data;

        if let Some(controller) = controller.as_mut() {
            controller.update(data);
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f79de53b1b37024aa420daf40ec42efc)

Splitting borrows works in most cases because you don't really need to borrow all the fields of the struct. In your case, you shouldn't need to pass the controller a reference to itself, so borrowing everything except that should be adequate.

Answer (score 1):

If you intend to compile your code with existing design approach, you could do something like this:

```
impl Entity{

    fn update(&mut self){
      // Take controller out of its original place 
      if let Some(mut contrl) = self.controller.take() {
           contrl.update(self);
           // replace it back
           self.controller = Some(contrl);
       }
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f7423bf8b947ba08d6cdab64b3f8e730)

In my opinion, you should try to avoid these kinds of circular dependencies.